# Android: Changing one number picker cause other number picker to change

Tags: java, android, android-listview, numberpicker

I have created a listview. Each item in list view has two UI elements. One is a textview and other is a number picker. Now the issue is that if i click on first number picker to change value, the fourth one also changes and vice versa. Here is my getview function

```
private class ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public NumberPicker numberPicker;
        public CustomListener listener;
    }

 public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View listItem = convertView;
        currentCell=getItem(position);
        currentCell.setPosition(position);
        if (listItem == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            listItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.organ_item, parent, false);
        }
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.organName);
            holder.numberPicker = (NumberPicker) 
            listItem.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
            holder.numberPicker.setMinValue(1);
            holder.numberPicker.setMaxValue(10);
            holder.numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(holder.listener);

            holder.numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            currentCell=getItem(position);
            View parentRow = (View) picker.getParent();
            ListView mListView=(ListView)parentRow.getParent().getParent();

            ConstraintLayout constraintLayoutView = (ConstraintLayout) mListView.getChildAt(currentCell.getPosition());

            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)constraintLayoutView.getChildAt(0);
            NumberPicker p = (NumberPicker) relativeLayout.getChildAt(1);
            if(position==currentCell.getPosition()) 
              {
                p.setValue(newVal);
              }
            else
              {
                 p.setValue(oldVal);
               }
                }
            });
            //Set the name
            TextView organName = (TextView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.organName);

 organName.setText(QuickMeditationScreenInfo.getInstance().getScreenNameFromIndex(currentCell.getOrgan()));
        return listItem;
    }
```

Also even if i comment out the onValueChangeListener even then the same behaviour occurs which i assume is the default behaviour of number picker in a list. I have spent multiple hours on it but couldn't figure out the solution. I have also debugged the code and when i change a value, the debugger comes into the onValueChange code only once.

Comment: your problem seem to be similar to the issues faced when having editable fields in list items like checkbox or edit text and there are lot of solutions available for them. You can try the same approach here

Answer (score 0):

You need set numberpicker default value every time

```
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.name = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.organName);
    holder.numberPicker = (NumberPicker) ;
    holder.numberPicker.setValue(defaultValue);//like this
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle click event into adapter using interface like below 
for example make one interface into adapter class ..

```
    private onItemClick onItemClick;

public void setOnItemClick(DisplayAllData.onItemClick onItemClick) {
    this.onItemClick = onItemClick;
}

public interface onItemClick{
    void onItemSelected(int position); // pass your data 
}
```

In getView() method like number listner called all logical code into activity or fragment.

```
        holder.mTvName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClick.onItemSelected(position);
        }
    });
```

In activity or fragment after adapter set into listview or recyclerview then
adapter not null then called below code..

```
allDataAdapter.setOnItemClick(new DisplayAllData.onItemClick() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(int position) {
                    // here called all logical part
                    allDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```